# @Secured on Spring controllers and context mess

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

For web MVC I need at least two configs: `dispatcher-servlet.xml` and `applicationContext.xml`. I use the following filter for security:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This filter needs `springSecurityFilterChain`, defined in `applicationContext.xml` with `<security:http />`

However, I want to use `@Secured` annotation on a `@Controller`, defined in `dispatcher-servlet.xml`. Again, this needs `<security:http />` - **in another context file!**

All I'm trying to achieve is security on `@Controller` level. I don't care about securing deeper layers (`@Service` etc.) at all since this is the only entry point.

What is my way out of this mess? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable security annotations for controllers you only need to add `<security:global-method-security ... />` to `dispatcher-servlet.xml`. Other security-related stuff stays in `applicationContext.xml`.

Comment: Strangely, when I set this up the `@RequestMapping` is ignored. I can see "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/myview.do] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'" in log. I expected to be redirected to login page. How do I achieve this?

Comment: @Konrad: If controller implements any interface, you need to add `proxy-target-class = "true"`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375753/spring-security-3-spring-mvc-and-the-dreaded-secured-requestmapping

Comment: Nice, that did the trick (my controller used to extend an abstract class). Another problem showed up: The controller is instantiated twice (the second time from AOP, it seems). Is that normal?