# Using Spring Security annotation on a method of a controller that extends another class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have very similar spring-security beans configuation to [this example](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html). The `@Secured` annotation on controller's methods only function properly if it is on a method of a class that does not subclass another class. In other words, this following code does not work (an exception raised during the bean initializtion):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/systeminfo")
public class SystemInfoController extends AbstractViewableController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/")
    @Secured("ROLE_USER") // an exception below was raised
    public void view(HttpServletRequest request) {
    }
}
```

Here is the exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit
h name 'systemInfoController' defined in file [C:\workspace\my\my-webapp
\target\classes\my\webapp\controller\SystemInfoController.class]: Initializa
tion of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopCo
nfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class my.webapp.c
ontroller.SystemInfoController]: Common causes of this problem include using a f
inal class or a non-visible class; nested exception is net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGen
erationException: java.lang.RuntimeException-->RequestMapping annotation cannot
be found on my.webapp.controller.SystemInfoController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$e99f
e366
```

So I follow the instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2376030/507546) and add `proxy-target-class="true"` to `<global-method-security  ...>` (Not sure if it is related) but the security aspect is still lost. However, if the superclass is removed, then the security get applied properly, i.e. forward to login page.

**Does anyone know what is going on and how to fix the problem when the controller needs to extend another class?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is highly probably a bug in spring bean factory, spring annotation scanner or the the generation of subclass using CGLIB. Spring should not scan the annotation on the subclasses that are generated by CGLIB directly since they are lost. It should scan its target class. In this case, it tried to scan `@ResquestMapping` on `my.webapp.controller.SystemInfoController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$e99fe366`.

However, since the whole thing works if `SystemInfoController` doesn't extend an abstrat class. It indicates that the annotation may be lost only when the controller is a subclass which suggests that this may be a bug in generating proxy subclass or a limitation of CGLIB.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled secured-annotations in your security.xml file

```
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
```

Moreover, these annotations only work for Spring beans. You need to inject these beans rather than just creating normal instances. Try using Spring Dependency Injection.

Comment: you need to do it before <http> or <secured:http>

Comment: yes, but I don't think you need it before <http> since it works fine if I don't subclass.

Comment: This is Spring MVC problem so the controller beans are created by spring dispatcher of spring context loader. Thus, yes.

Comment: and since the `@Secured` annotation works when the controller isn't a subclass, so DI is already working.

Comment: very right. Please do one test try making a new class and move your @Secured method to that new class and then invoke it from this class after injecting its bean in this class.

Comment: You mean create a `Component` annotated class? That probably works for the component since the component bean aren't subclass but I don't think that solves this error since it complains that `@RequestMapping` is not found on the controller class which Spring Security tries to create a subclass proxy of it. The real problem is that the annotations on subclass seem to be lost when a `@Secured` annotation is declared.